# call concurrent futures from inside a function in another file

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

How can I use parallel computing sitting inside a function in another file that is being imported?

Here as an example I created a file scratch_tests.py

```
import concurrent.futures

def g():
    print(__name__)

    global f
    def f(x):
        return x**2

    if __name__=='scratch_tests':
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            t = executor.submit(f, 2)
        return t.result()
```

In another file I execute these lines:

```
from scratch_tests import g

g()
```

It exectedly errors out. How in principle one handles this type of cases where the concurrent computations need to happen inside a function residing in some file?

```
> BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated
> abruptly while the future was running or pending
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled): _"functions (built-in and user-defined) accessible from the top level of a module"_. Since multiprocessing does use pickling as a means of data transfer between processes this won't work as long as you use functions defined inside functions. If you move the definition of `f` outside of `g` this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the platform you are running on but given the issue you are having it seems likely that it is one that uses the *spawn* method for creating child processes. I will attempt to provide an answer based on that assumption.

As mentioned by Timus, you need to make function `f` a global function *by moving it to global scope*; declaring it as global but keeping it where it is as a function nested within `g` accomplished nothing. But you have another, major issue:

The way child processes are initialized when *spawn* is being used is that a new Python interpreter is launched in the child process. The address space for this new process is initially uninitialized, i.e. it does not inherit a copy of the parent's memory. Thus the Python interpreter re-processes all the Python modules executing all definitions at the global scope, which includes the function definitions and any other global data you will need by your child process. You can surround code at the global scope (or at any level but it is usually pointless to do this for any level except the global scope) with a test of the current module name to conditionally execute that code. **This, however, only seems to make sense if you do this in the main script whose `__name__` value will change if it is being executed in a child process as part of its initialization. For other modules, the `__name__` variable is invariant, so what is the point of testing it?**

Let me elaborate:

The module name of the main script has name `'__main__'` in the parent process and name `'__mp_main__'` in any child process. The module name for your *scratch_tests.py* file **will always be `'scratch_tests'` regardless if is in the main or child process.** Therefore, the test you have in function `g`, namely `if __name__ == 'scratch_tests':` will always evaluate to `True` regardless and accomplishes nothing. When `g` is initially called from the main script it will create the pool and submit a task to the pool creating some number of pool child processes. For each of these processes your main script will be re-interpreted and `g` will be recursively called again leading to a catastrophic error. Therefore:

1. Remove the `__name__` test from `g` since it accomplishes nothing.
2. Add the following test for `__name__` in your main script:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from scratch_tests import g

    g()
```

This will prevent `g` from being called recursively.

**Summary**

You must include a `if __name__ == '__main__':` test in your main script around any global code that directly creates a child process or indirectly creates a child process by executing code that creates a child process.

Consequently, if you have in your main script a function `foobar` that creates a child process, don't put the name test in `foobar`; put it around code at global scope that directly or indirectly results in `foobar` being called. **You can also include the name test around any definitions at global scope in the main script that are not required by child processes as a matter of efficiency**:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This definition is not referenced by worker (i.e. child processes):
    my_list = [some very large list that takes a lot of memory]

def worker(value):
    ....

def foobar():
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(worker, my_list)

def main():
    ...
    foobar()
    ...

# This is where the test should be:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: why is it that I need the guard `if __name__ == '__main__':` in python file but don't need it when running from jupyter cell?

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals of `Jupyter` to be able to answer in detail. I could conjecture that the `Jupyter` cell is not "at global scope." But if you are running from the command line on a platform such as Windows that is using the *spawn* method to create new processes, **you need it**. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods). It doesn't explain the "why" in details, at least not to the extent that I do above.